# Jquery validation of a form split across multiple hidden DIVs

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I've created a form that is split into 2 DIVs. When the user clicks the NEXT button, I want to do 2 things: 1. Validate the text fields in the first DIV, and if successful; 2. Hide the first DIV and fadein the second DIV (if validation fails, show a message, and prevent the display of the 2nd part of the form).

I've stripped down my code. This is the script that currently hides the first DIV when clicking on an image button. I do not know how to modify this script to execute the validation on the fields, preventing the first DIV from hiding and the second one showing:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.nextlink").click(function (event) {
    $("#partone").hide();
    $("#parttwo").fadeIn("slow");
  });    
</script>
```

The Form is as follows:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="registration">

<div id="partone">
Name:* <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" />
<img src="images/arrow.png" id="arrow" class="nextlink" alt="next">
</div>    

<div id="parttwo">
Address*: <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
<INPUT TYPE="image" src="images/arrow.png" alt="Submit">
</div>

</form>
```

CSS:

```
div#partone {   
}
div#parttwo {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the hide() and fadeIn() inside a if clause that checks if the first part of the form is valid.

```
function validateFirstPart() {
  if($('#customer_name').val().length < 1){
    alert("Too short customer name");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.nextlink").click(function (event) {
        if(validateFirstPart()){
            $("#partone").hide();
            $("#parttwo").fadeIn("slow");
        }
});
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but yes, this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to stop the first DIV from disappearing.

<script><br>
$(document).ready(function(){

function validateFirstPart() {
  if($('#customer_name').value.length =0){
    alert("Please enter a customer name.");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$("#next").click(function (event) {
if(validateFirstPart()){
 $("#partone").hide();
 $("#parttwo").fadeIn("slow");}
});

Comment: I thought you would want it to disappear. You can remove the hide() to make it stay as it is.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear -- #partone should disappear only if #customer_name is not empty.

Comment: Then you have to validate the field so that the function returns false if the field is empty. For example $('#customer_name').value.length < 1 or any other way you might find out if it is empty. EDIT: I see you used .length = 0 there. You need to use == to compare, = is for assigning variables and wont work.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/SK4gQ/1/ The problem was probably in the .value, that should be .val() in jQuery.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! That worked. I've edited your original code to reflect the correct result. What if I had a second form field in the first DIV? How would you stack the IF statements so that more than one field is validated before going onto the next DIV?

Comment: Just add the next if statement in the validateFirstPart after the first one (and before the return true;) and the next after the last and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Yes. It works as follows:

```
function validateFirstPart() {
  if($('#customer_name').val().length < 1){
    alert("Too short customer name");
    return false;
  }
  if($('#ranch').val().length < 1){
    alert("Too short ranch name");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.nextlink").click(function (event) {
        if(validateFirstPart()){
            $("#partone").hide();
            $("#parttwo").fadeIn("slow");
        }
});
```